# Add a Duration to DateTime in XSLT

Tags: datetime, xslt, date, time

In an XSLT, I want to convert an XML document to another one. The old document has some dates and times that aren't really easy to use. For example:

```
<foo date="20110310" time="002000" duration="001500"/>
```

Now I extracted all the information and was able to convert these to ISO 8601 dates:

```
<xsl:variable name="begin" select='concat($begin_date_year, "-", $begin_date_month, "-", $begin_date_day, "T", $begin_time_hour, ":", $begin_time_minutes, ":", $begin_time_seconds)'/>
--> $begin = 2011-03-10T00:20:00
```

And for the duration:

```
<xsl:variable name="duration" select='concat("PT", $dur_hour, ":", $dur_minutes, ":", $dur_seconds)'/>
--> $duration = PT00:15:00
```

How can I **add the duration to the DateTime** in order to find out the end (in a DateTime format)?

I already thought about adding the individual components, but this would involve a lot of fiddling around with moduli, for example if I added 15 minutes to 23:50 and then had to adjust the day accordingly, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, now I [found a function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-add-dayTimeDuration-to-dateTime) that wasn't listed in the function reference that I used before.

```
add-dayTimeDuration-to-dateTime(xs:dateTime, xs:dayTimeDuration)
```

This could also be written, for example, as:

```
xs:dateTime($begin) + xs:dayTimeDuration($duration)
```

Comment: That's XPath 2.0 and formaly it's an operator that _backs up the "`+`" operator on `xs:dateTime` and `xs:dayTimeDuration` values_

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, there is also an implementaton on http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/add/date.add.html

See a similar question at [xslt - subtracting days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885292/xslt-subtracting-days)