# subtract days from date in xslt SPD

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, sharepoint-designer

how to subtract days from current date in Sharepoint Designer XSLT for filtering a dataview web part?

Comment: possible duplicate of [xslt - subtracting days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885292/xslt-subtracting-days)

Comment: Rather than depending on XSLT modification,I instead created a simple calculated field in my list to subtract days from my Start Date value. I filtered the list in SPD based on this calculated value. Serves the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@DateValue), 1033, 'dd')"/>
```

Comment: @wk: what am i supposed to do with the day from the date??